# Images not loading in React app when deployed on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, image, heroku, deployment

I'm a new React developer attempting to deploy my first React app on Heroku.

All the images load fine locally, but no longer load when deployed on Heroku.

Here is the link to my site: https://yom-recipes.herokuapp.com/

Each box is supposed to load an image dynamically from a prop link passed over from another component.

The images are located in a folder within src.

```
<img src={require(`../images/${props.link}.jpg`)} alt={props.name}/>
```

Any insight deeply appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.btn-note img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-bottom: -25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* opacity: 1%; */ comment here
    z-index: 1;
}
```

remove opacity style to show your image

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize Heroku uses the 0-1.0 metric instead of percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your opacity

```
.btn-note img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-bottom: -25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

instead of opacity: 1%;, increase it to 100%